# Font issue when trying to export file from ReportViewer Control

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I am using `ReportViewer control` to export data as word document(doc). when I download the file it appears like this: 

[image] 

*There is problem with Arabic font as you see*, English words are okay.
 Do you know how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the Table > from Localization > choose LayoutDirection to "RTL"